# How can I use natbib citation style in a specific template?

Tags: natbib, bibliographystyle

I'm working with [the NeurIPS template on overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/neurips-2022/kxymzbjpwsqx).
From my reading, I understand that `natbib` is the default package for reference.
I tried to read the instruction carefully and also read the official Overleaf's tutorial on `natbib`.

But I still can't use the reference *normally*?
I prefer to have references in a separate file, e.g, `my_ref.bib` that contains:

```
@inproceedings{Arora2018StrongerGB,
  title={Stronger generalization bounds for deep nets via a compression approach},
  author={Sanjeev Arora and Rong Ge and Behnam Neyshabur and Yi Zhang},
  booktitle={International Conference on Machine Learning},
  year={2018}
}
```

and then in `main.tex`, I do this:

```
\section*{References}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{my_ref}
```

[Edited] I added the `IEEEtran.bst` file.

and then use `\cite{Arora2018StrongerGB}` in the `main.tex`. I also tried `citet{Arora2018StrongerGB}`. But it also doesn't work with this template.

[image]

[image]

Feel free to inspect the project: https://www.overleaf.com/8778352361kqjtqqkyncyw

Any recommendation is appreciated. Thanks!

Here's the content of the log `output.blg`

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2022)
Capacity: max_strings=200000, hash_size=200000, hash_prime=170003
The top-level auxiliary file: output.aux
The style file: IEEEtran.bst
You've used 1 entry,
            0 wiz_defined-function locations,
            87 strings with 538 characters,
and the built_in function-call counts, 0 in all, are:
= -- 0
> -- 0
< -- 0
+ -- 0
- -- 0
* -- 0
:= -- 0
add.period$ -- 0
call.type$ -- 0
change.case$ -- 0
chr.to.int$ -- 0
cite$ -- 0
duplicate$ -- 0
empty$ -- 0
format.name$ -- 0
if$ -- 0
int.to.chr$ -- 0
int.to.str$ -- 0
missing$ -- 0
newline$ -- 0
num.names$ -- 0
pop$ -- 0
preamble$ -- 0
purify$ -- 0
quote$ -- 0
skip$ -- 0
stack$ -- 0
substring$ -- 0
swap$ -- 0
text.length$ -- 0
text.prefix$ -- 0
top$ -- 0
type$ -- 0
warning$ -- 0
while$ -- 0
width$ -- 0
write$ -- 0
```

Comment: Have you added the \bibliographystyle{} command with a bibliography style file (.bst) in your project?

Comment: Without a `\bibliographystyle` instruction, BibTeX doesn't have information to work. Have you checked the `.blg` ("BibTeX log") file for errors and/or warnings?

Comment: Hi @Mico, I added \bibliographystyle but it still doesn't work. Can you give another recommendation? I edited the content of my question.

Comment: @Van-TienPHAM - What's the argument of the `\bibliographystyle` directive? And, did you run a full recompile cycle -- LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more?

Comment: @Mico Thanks for your help. A full recompile made it works.

Comment: However, I had to uncomment this line to make it completely works:

\PassOptionsToPackage{numbers, compress}{natbib}